# Facebook Pages API Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift

I'm new in programming in swift. I'm trying to read Facebook pages posts(wall) from a public page and show the content(images and messages) in my app without users login. I've already set up the app with Facebook SDK (plist, bridging-Header.h etc...). I know I must open a session and pass a valid access token to the Facebook server. But I can't understand how....

below my viewDidLoad

```
let request = "/(pageID)?fields=id,posts"

FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath(request, completionHandler: {(connection:     FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error? != nil){
            NSLog("error = \(error)")


        }else{
            println(result)



        }

    } as FBRequestHandler)
```

I get this error:

```
An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.

com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 104;
        message = "An access token is required to request this resource.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}}
```

i think i need to open a session in AppDelegate and so I can make the request I've also read the Facebook documentation but I haven't found the answer.

Please help me. Thank you!!!

Comment: hey :)
did you solve this error ?
i faced the same problem too ..